# DataBinding feedback in .NET2

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, .net-2.0

I have a object myObject.Name in a Form1 with a textBox1
In the Form1_Load I do:

```
this.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", myObject, "Name");
```

When validating the textBox I have myObject.Name changed. This is **OK**.

Now I modify internally in myObject `_name = "changed value"`, but myTextBox text will not change. so... how to do it on both directions, *from* and *to* the textBox1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) so that the data binding knows that your object changed.

Comment: ...and then the next line after `_name = "changed value"` must be something like `PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));`. Basically, you are creating an event that gets fired whenever a property changes, but *you have to implement the firing of that event in your setters*.